# this.state is null inside render React and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am a novice in ReactJS. Was watching a tutorial that is recorded in ES6 JavaScript and simultaneously I am trying to recreate the same app in TypeScript (I am a novice in TypeScript too!!). In ES6 we need to use a class based approach if that particular component needs to maintain it's own state. I have installed `"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties"` so i do set state in ES6 as `export default class SomeClass { state = {
someProperty : someValue }}`. But in TypeScript I am using class based approach for every component. So here is a component that tries to maintain it's own state:

```js
import React from 'react';

interface IAddOptionProps {
    handleAddOption: (option: string) => string |null;
};

interface IAddOptionState {
    error: any;
};

export default class AddOption extends React.Component<IAddOptionProps, IAddOptionState> {
    handleAddOption = (e:any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const option = e.target.elements.option.value.trim();
        const err : string = this.props.handleAddOption(option);

        this.setState(() => {
            return {
                error: err
            }
        });

        if (!err) {
            e.target.elements.option.value = '';
        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state);
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.error != null ? <p>{this.state.error}</p> : ''}
                <form onSubmit={this.handleAddOption}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Enter an Option</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="option"  name="option"/>
                    </div>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary">Add option</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

The statement `console.log(this.state);` and  `{this.state.error != null ? <p>{this.state.error}</p> : ''}` inside render() is throwing error stating that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of null`. That means `this.state` is being set as null.

Why is state getting set to null and how do I resolve this ( In TypeScript )?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: because you didn't define the state, put this inside class: `state = {error: ''}` or use constructor.

Comment: Thanks. But I have declared an Interface and passed it as a Generic argument. Isn't it sufficient?

Comment: What about super() method call? I am not seeing it

Comment: In super() props will be passed on to the parent component, but I want state only to be maintained in this component.

Comment: I have one more question, we need to use super(props) only if we define a constructor, if we don't need a constructor in a particular component then no need of super(props)? My doubt is ```constructor(props) { super(props); }``` is mandatory or optional.

Comment: Agreed. But 'this' will be initiated only by doing super(). without parameters (I guess)

Comment: If you add a constructor, super() call is compulsory.

Comment: Without placing ```state = { error: ''}``` a class property and place a constructor like ```constructor() { super(); }``` won't work. I tried. super() expects props as an argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you have to initialize the state either in the constructor or with a property initializer like this:

```
class AddOption extends React.Component<IAddOptionProps, IAddOptionState> {

  this.state = {
    error: ''
  };

  [...]

}
```

Otherwise `state` will be null and you will get an error like mentioned in your post.

Comment: Thanks. I initialized state as a property and it’s working now

Comment: Not sure if it's a version thing, but i believe *this* needs to be omitted now. If i add it without it being in a constructor, I get an error  this.state = become state =

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize your state. There are two ways to do that

The first is to use a property initializer

```
class AddOption extends React.Component<IAddOptionProps, IAddOptionState> {

  this.state = {
    error: ''
  };

  render() {

    // Now you have your state! Do stuff here

  }

}
```

The other way is to do it in the constructor

```
class AddOption extends React.Component<IAddOptionProps, IAddOptionState> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      error: ''
    };
  }

  render() {

    // Now you have your state! Do stuff here

  }

}
```

The solutions are equivalent, though the first is more elegant

Comment: The second gives a warning in my case

Comment: What warning do you get @DaveHillier?